# Binary function which added to itself, arguments switched, gives a constant

Tags: functions, terminology

Say I have the function
$$
f_1(x, y) = \frac{x}{x + y} \label{a}\tag{1}
$$
or
$$
f_2(x, y) = \frac{y - x}{x + y} \label{b}\tag{2}
$$
or
$$
f_3(x, y) = x - y \label{c}\tag{3}
$$

Then $f(a, b) + f(b, a) = c$ for any $a$ and $b$.

Is there a name for such a property?
If there is no short name for it, how would you describe it?

So far I've said that the function and its commutation(?) are additively inverse, around some value $d = c/2$. In the case of $(\ref{b})$ and $(\ref{c})$ that value would be $0$, in $(\ref{a})$ it would be $0.5$

Comment: I have no idea of the name but describing it as "$f(a,b) + f(b,a)=c$ for all $a,b,$" seems a more than adequate description to me.  Or $f(a,b) = -f(b,a) + C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the special case when $c=0$ it's called an [alternating function](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alternating_function). I don't think it has a name for general $c$.

We do have in general that $f(x,y)-\frac c2$ is alternating, though.

Comment: For any non-zero $c$ value, $f (x,y)-c/2$ would be an alternating function :)

Comment: @CiaPan That's right. It even says so in my answer :)

Comment: Didn't see that part when I was writing my comment.